# Random Combination of r from set of integers 'n' without repetition

Tags: php, math

I want to group of integers (r) randomly from set of integers (n). For example n = 1,2,3,4,5,6 and r = 3, I want the output as {1,2,3} {4,5,6} so-on... but if 1 is used in one group i don't want it other group.. so-on. I want one unique combination as output. How can i do this in PHP ??

This code gives all combination without randomness

```
// view the real output 
header('Content-Type: text/plain'); 

// your string 
$letters = 'RAT'; 

// convert to array 
$letters_array = array("RAT1 ", "RAT2 ", "RAT3 ", "RAT4 ", "RAT5 ","RAT6 ", "RAT7", "RAT8", "RAT9", "RAT10");

echo 'The number of two charcter combinations from that string is '.count($result = get_combos($letters_array, 3))."\n\n";

echo 'The following is the combinations array'."\n\n"; 

print_r(array_2d_to_1d($result)); 

function get_combos($input, $combo_length) 
{ 
    $input = array_values($input); 
    $code = ''; 
    $cnt = count($input); 
    $ret = array(); 
    $i0 = -1; 
    for($i=0;$i<$combo_length;++$i) 
    { 
        $k = 'i'.($i+1); 
        $code .= 'for($'.$k.'=$i'.$i.'+1; $'.$k.'< $cnt-'.($combo_length-$i-1).'; ++$'.$k.') '; 
    } 
    $code .= '$ret[] = array($input[$i'.implode('], $input[$i',range(1,$combo_length)).']);';
    eval($code); 
    return $ret; 
} 

function str_2_array($input) 
{ 
    for($i = 0, $len = strlen($input); $i < $len; $i++) 
    { 
        $rtn[] = $input[$i]; 
    } 
    return $rtn; 
} 

function array_2d_to_1d($input) 
{ 
    foreach($input as $key => $value) 
    { 
        $rtn[$key] = implode($value); 
    } 
    return $rtn; 
}
```

Comment: Please add an example output for an input with non unique numbers, for example for `n = 1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 2, 5, 5, 9, 7` and `r = 4`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a PHP guy so there will be no code here. But as for algorithm I think what you need is:

1. Optionally strip non-unique values from the source array
2. Perform [random shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) of the array
3. Slice the shuffled array into sub-arrays of required length.